# future got attached to different loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous

```
Task <Task pending name='Task-11' coro=<Queue.get() running at C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\queues.py:166> cb=[_release_waiter(<Future pendi...15C1F7220>()]>)() at C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py:416]> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop
```

The above error is what I recieved when deploying code in command prompt on an EC2 instance. But this kind of error does not occur in my personal computer. the code works fine in my personal computer's command prompt.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for enquiring, the problem is solved the code was totally fine, the problem was with the package. My EC2 instance had the latest version of the library, downgrading it solved the issue